# ArrayList в Java

Tags: java

```
class Dlist<T1,T2>{

     ArrayList<T1> value;
     ArrayList<ArrayList<T2>> val;

     Dlist() {

         value = new ArrayList<>(20);
         val = new ArrayList<>(20);
     }
         Dlist(int n) {
             value = new ArrayList<>(n);
             val = new ArrayList<>(n);

         }

         public<T1,T2> void add(T1 num1,ArrayList<T2> num2){
             ArrayList<T2> g = new ArrayList<>();
            value.add(num1);
            val.addAll(num2);
         }
     }
```

Почему в функции добавления, я не могу добавить в массивы элементы шаблона?

'add(T1)' in 'java.util.ArrayList' cannot be applied to '(T1)'

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> public<T1,T2> void add(T1 num1,ArrayList<T2> num2){
> ```

```
public void add(T1 num1,ArrayList<T2> num2){
```

Comment: а , лол, я че то даже не заметил. спасибо